# Gradle custom rule classes

Tags: gradle, build

I know that it's possible to create custom task classes by extending the `DefaultTask` class. Is it possible to do the same with task rules? Which class would I have to extend and how? Let's say I want to get a custom rule class equivalent of this rule from Gradle documentation:

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: ping<ID>") { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.startsWith("ping")) {
        task(taskName) {
           doLast {
               println "Pinging: " + (taskName - 'ping')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Gradle 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by writing a plugin as described here: https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/custom_plugins.html

```
package com.domain

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class PingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.tasks.addRule("Pattern: ping<ID>") { String taskName ->
            if (taskName.startsWith("ping")) {
                project.tasks.create(taskName) {
                    doLast {
                        println "Pinging: " + (taskName - 'ping')
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works. All it takes to use it is one line in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: com.domain.PingPlugin
```